# Creating a Listview filter in WPF with a text box search

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, filter

I am creating an application with an XML file called star.xml to store my data in a list view. I am very new to c# and programming and need any help 
Basically, I want to be able to type in my search text box (called 'search') and for my list view (lstStar) to only show the matching records. I.e. typing in 'Audi' will only return those items. 
any help will be much appreciated
jen

```
namespace StarinCar
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int hot = -2;
        int Mildly_Moist = -2;
        int Wet = -4;
        int Very_Wet = -6;
        private ObservableCollection<star> starData;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            starData = new ObservableCollection<star>();
            lstStar.ItemsSource = starData;

            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<star>));
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader("star.xml"))
                {
                    starData = xs.Deserialize(rd) as ObservableCollection<star>;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            lstStar.ItemsSource = starData;

            lblAverage.Content = starData.Average(i => i.time).ToString();
            lblFastest.Content = starData.Min(i => i.time).ToString();
            lblSlowest.Content = starData.Max(i => i.time).ToString();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            star newStar = new star();

            newStar.firstName = txtName.Text;
            newStar.time = int.Parse(txtTime.Text);  
            newStar.car = txtCar.Text;
            newStar.track = txtTrack.Text;

            starData.Add(newStar);

            if (txtTrack.Text.Contains("Hot") || (txtTrack.Text.Contains("hot") == true))
            {
                newStar.time = int.Parse(txtTime.Text) + hot;
            }

            if (txtTrack.Text.Contains("Mildly Moist") || (txtTrack.Text.Contains("mildly moist")) == true)
            {
                newStar.time = int.Parse(txtTime.Text) + Mildly_Moist;
            }

            if (txtTrack.Text.Contains("Wet") || (txtTrack.Text.Contains("wet") == true))
            {
                newStar.time = int.Parse(txtTime.Text) + Wet;
            }

            if (txtTrack.Text.Contains("Very Wet") || (txtTrack.Text.Contains("very wet")) == true)
            {
                newStar.time = int.Parse(txtTime.Text) + Very_Wet;
            }
        }

        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<star>));
            using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("star.xml"))
            {
                xs.Serialize(wr, starData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code for your listbox and searchbox, and their xaml?  when do you want your listbox to update its list of stars?  ie. do you have a button that you click after you are done typing "Audi", or is it supposed to continually update whiel you type or what?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Don't include code that has nothing to do with the question.  Don't have lots of  blank lines.   Search TextBox is buried at then end.   Bind to an iEnumerable that is filtered by Search.

Comment: OK question needs some clean up by edit out all the XAML is a little far.   Now there is not XAML for  I want to be able to type in my search text box (called 'search') and for my list view (lstStar) .

Answer (score 1):

You could use ICollectionView.  So you would have your "overall"
 star collection 'starData'.  But your listbox itemssource would be bound to something like this:

```
public ICollectionView FilteredStars
    {
        get
        {
            ICollectionView source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(starData);
            source.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterStars);

            return source;
        }
    }
```

the logic that does the filtering here:

```
private bool FilterStars(object item)
    {
        bool b = false;
        star a = item as star;

        if (a != null)
        {
            if (a.Name.Contains(searchBoxText))  //your filter logic here
            {
                   b = true;
            }
            else if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchBoxText)
            {
                   b = true;
            }
        }

        return b;
    }
```

Basically, you have your main collection, then some logic that filters your main collection to a filtered collection, and that's what you should set itemssource of your listbox to.  This, so far, is assuming you are going to put some kind of property change into your search text box and probably then click a button, like "Search" to then tell the list to check and re-populate to match the search term.

Comment: Old but, works perfectly !

Answer (score -1):

This is how I filter in a similar application

```
    public IEnumerable<string> PastEntries1
    {
        get
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textValue))
            {
                return FieldDefString.PastEntries;
            }
            else 
            {
                return FieldDefString.PastEntries.Where(x => x.StartsWith(textValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }
        }
    }
```